# How can I convert assembly code into binary code?

Tags: assembly, binary, x86-64, instruction-encoding

I created a simple c++ source file with the following code:

```cpp
    int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    if(a < b) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(a > b) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I used the `objdump` command to get the assembly code for the above source code.
The line `int b = 2;` got converted into `mov DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4], 0x2`.
Its corresponding machine code is `C7 45 FC 02 00 00 00` (hex format).

*I would like to know how I can convert assembly code into binary code*. I went through the Intel Reference Manual for x86-64, but I was not able to understand it, since I am new to low level programming.

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert'? Using a program? Doing it manually?

Comment: Converting it manually.

Comment: `int b = 2;` is NOT Assembly language. The difference is, that C is compiled language, so the line `int b = 2;` may be implemented in many different ways (even removed completely by optimizer), depending on what compiler will decide, how to produce machine code which will produce results as defined by C language standard. Assembly language is different in a way, that Assembler is not compiler of this kind, when you write in Assembly `add rax,rbx`, it will be compiled as that, not changing the instruction, or removing by some kind of optimizer, so that's more like "1:1 transformation".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the Intel manuals, it explains how to do that. For a simpler reference, [read this](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding). The way x86 instructions are encoded is fairly straightforward, but the number of possibilities can be a bit overwhelming.

In a nutshell, an x86 instruction comprises the following parts, where every part except the opcode may be missing:

```
prefix opcode operands immediate
```

The `prefix` field may modify the behaviour of the instruction, which doesn't apply to your use case. You can look up the `opcode` in a reference (I like [this one](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek64.html)), for example, `mov r/m32, imm32` is `C7 /0` which means: The opcode is `C7` and one of the two operands is zero, encoding an extended opcode.  The instruction thus has the form

```
C7 /0 imm32
```

The operand/extended opcode is encoded as a modr/m byte with an optional sib (scale index base) byte for some addressing modes and an optional 8 bit or 32 bit displacement. You can look up what value you need [in the reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek64.html#modrm_byte_32_64). So in your case, you want to encode a memory operand `[rbp]` with a one byte displacement and a register operand of 0, leading to the modr/m byte `45`. So the encoding is:

```
C7 45 disp8 imm32
```

Now we encode the 8 bit displacement in two's complement. `-4` corresponds to `FC`, so this is

```
C7 45 FC imm32
```

Lastly, we encode the 32 bit immediate, which you want to be `2`. Note that it is in little endian:

```
C7 45 FC 02 00 00 00
```

And that's how the instruction is encoded.

Comment: So int the the [link](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek64.html) you provided, I went to C7 1 Byte Opcode, and it is for **MOV** instruction. but what does the two operand Evqp and Ivds mean, do they correspond to rm32 addressing and immediate? Thank you for the help

Comment: See [this page](http://ref.x86asm.net/#column_op) for the meaning of the fields. The reference I linked is highly condensed but more difficult to read.

Comment: Okay great. Another question was that you said "I wanted to encode rbp register with 1 byte displacement(8 bits)[**DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]**]" , when I was seeing the table for MOD r/m in the [link](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek64.html#modrm_byte_32_64) I am also seeing a version of 32 bits displacements, can you give me an example of that?

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb With a 32 bit displacement, the encoding would be `C7 85 FC FF FF FF 02 00 00 00` where the modr/m byte is `85` instead of `45` and the displacement is `FC FF FF FF`.

Comment: So if **mov rbp,rsp** gets converted to **48 89 e5**, I get it that since both the operands are registers thus opcode is 89, and checking the table in [link](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek64.html#modrm_byte_32_64) and thus the mod r/m is e5, but I do not get by 48 is prefixed to the code, how did we get that?

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb The `48` prefix is a REX.W prefix. It indicates that the operand size is 64 bit instead of 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Another question, I know I am asking too many, its just that I am very much new to this, for exam I have instruction **mov edi, [ebx-0x4]**, this gets converted to **67 8b 7b fc**. I read in the manual and it said "Address override, 67h. Changes size of address expected by the instruction. 32-bit address could switch to 16-bit and vice versa."  Is that a valid understanding?

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb Seems correct. In 16 bit mode and 64 bit mode, `67` changes to 32 bit addressing mode. In 32 bit mode, it changes to 16 bit mode. In 64 bit mode, you should rarely need the `67` prefix.

Comment: Okay thank you. If I convert **mov  [ebp+0x79], ecx** to machine code I get **67 89 4d 79** which uses a 8 bit displacement, but when I convert **mov  [ebp+0x80], ecx** to machine code I get **67 89 8d 80 00 00 00** why does the second instruction uses 32 bit displacement when **80** can be represented in 8 bits.

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb Note that the displacement is a signed integer, so `67 89 5d 80` is actually `mov [ebp-0x80], ecx`. `+0x80` is the first displacement that can't be encoded in a single byte.

Comment: Okay thank you. So if I have the Instruction **mov [0x5], edx** and it gets converted to **89 14 25 05 00 00 00**. I am able to understand everything except why **25** is there?. I mean, according to mod r/m table I do get **14** when I check [sib] and edx. And the same for **mov [esp+4], ebp** I get **67 89 6c 24 04 ** but why **24** is there?

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb `25` is the SIB byte indicating a 32 bit absolute address. For your second example, `6c` indicates “[sib] + disp8, ebp” and 24 is the SIB byte, indicating `esp` as a base register and no index register.

Comment: Another query was that **mov eax, 0x55** translates to **b8 55 00 00 00** and **mov ebx, 0x55** translates to **bb 55 00 00 00** and **mov ecx, 0x55** translates to **b9 55 00 00 00**. All of them having different opcode. When all the them conform to the form **MOV r32, imm32** which has an opcode **B8+ rd id** according to intel manual

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb Look into the manual. There is a separate encoding for `mov reg32, imm32` which is `b8+reg`.

Comment: Okay got it, I was not able to understand the part **+reg** which means we have to add the 3 bits for the respective registers **001** for **ecx**

Comment: Instruction such as **jmp    40050b <main+0x35>** in objdump is showing as **eb 14** and **eb 05**, why do they have different machine code when they both are the same instruction?

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb That's because the jump target is encoded relative to were we are right now. EB 14 is “jump 14 bytes ahead,” not “jump to 40050b.” Of course, to reach the same target, you have to jump by a different amount from each source.

Comment: Okay. So I was reading somewhere, that **the x86 will not allow instructions greater than 15 bytes in length.** is it same for **x86-64** also, and how does these instructions fit into memory?

Comment: @AbhisheykDeb Can you please not ask hundreds of questions in comments? This is the last follow-up I am going to answer. Yes, the 15 byte limit applies to 64 bit moe, too. If an instruction-encoding would be longer than 15 byte, that instruction encoding is invalid.